# Do prime of the form $4k+1$ ever lead the greatest prime factor race?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, analytic-number-theory

**Note**: [Posted in MO since](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433862/do-prime-of-the-form-4k1-ever-lead-the-greatest-prime-factor-race) it is unanswered in MSE.

Analogous to Chebyshev's race between primes, I examined the race between primes in the [greatest prime factors, GPF](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatestPrimeFactor.html#:%7E:text=The%20greatest%20multiple%20prime%20factors,2%2C%203%2C%20...), of natural numbers. Similar to the regular prime race, in the GPF race, the proportion of prime of both forms is roughly $50\%$ each. However, unlike the regular prime race where the race is equal ([A038691](http://oeis.org/A038691)) or changes lead between primes of the form $4k+1$ and $4k+3$ ([A096628](http://oeis.org/A096628)) in the GPF race, $4k+3$ dominates. For $n \le 3 \times 10^{10}$, there are $14970975209$ numbers the GPF is of the form $4k+1$ and $15029024755$ numbers where $GPF$ is of the form $4k+3$ and up till this point, there is not a single instance where primes of the form $4k+1$ equal or take the lead in the race.

Let $f_1(n)$ and $f_3(n)$ be the number of natural numbers $\le n$ in which the GPF is of the form $4k+1$ and $4k+3$ respectively. The difference between the number of GPFs on these two forms appeared to increase in a very orderly manner as shown in the graph below.

[image]

**Question 1**: Does the GPF race ever become equal or change the lead i.e. is there an $n$ such that $f_1(n) = f_3(n)$?

Clearly, the graph is sub-linear. I applied different curve fitting models to this data to have an idea of the growth rate. The best fit was given by

$$
f_3(n) - f_1(n) \approx an^b
$$

where $a \approx 0.1785$ and $b \approx 0.8122$. This experimental model has a very high $R^2 = 0.9999958$. If this is close to the true growth rate then, prime of the form $4k+1$ will always lag behind in the GPF race.

**Question 2**: What is the true growth rate of $f_3(n) - f_1(n)$?

Comment: Wow, a huge search range (+1) !

Comment: The sum of the above numbers is $36$ less then $8\cdot 10^9$ , but there are only $33$ powers of $2$ (including $1$) upto $8\cdot 10^9$.  What do I miss ?

Comment: @Peter Very acute observation. Actually I was checking for primes of the form $6k \pm 1$ so I started the search from $p_4 = 7$. I modified the same code to search for primes of the form $4k /pm + 1$ but forgot to initialize to $p_2 = 3$.

Comment: OK, although $5$ is also a prime of the form $6k\pm 1$. Do you know the first crossover of the regular prime race ? A fair coin could not have given this number of heads/tails, but I think, the Chebycheff bias is similarily significant, so it might be too early to draw conslusions.

Comment: @Peter For the regular prime race, crossover happen quite frequently with the smallest at $n = 2946$. More: http://oeis.org/A096628

Comment: More precisely, at the $2946$th prime, which is $n=26861$. There are several other places below $8\cdot10^9$ as well: see the middle of page 2 of [my paper with Granville](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/PNR.pdf).

Comment: $f_3(x)-f_1(x) = - \sum_{p\le x} \chi_{-4}(p) \psi(\frac xp,p)$, where $\chi_{-4}$ is the nontrivial Dirichlet character modulo $4$ and $\psi(t,y)$ is the number of integers up to $t$ whose prime factors are all at most $y$ (the "$y$-friable" numbers). This is turn is asymptotically $- \sum_{p\le x} \chi_{-4}(p) \rho(\frac{\log x}{\log p}-1)$, where $\rho$ is the Dickman–de Bruijn function related to friable numbers. One could try finding an explicit formula for this using Perron's formula, treating the $\rho$ factor as a smoothing term....

Comment: @GregMartin A very interesting paper. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: @GregMartin How do you know this is the asymptotic?

Comment: @NilotpalSinha since you have the data, can you share a histogram of the GPFs? Curious how many numbers have GPF less than a certain number.

Comment: @sku Yes, I have the data for $n \le 77258000000$ will share them shortly. Any idea how I share an excel or csv file in MSE?

Comment: Put on gdrive and share link

Comment: @GregMartin One problem with using the asymptotic for $\psi(\frac{x}{p},p)$ to obtain an asymptotic for $\sum_{p\leq x} \chi(p)\psi(\frac{x}{p},p)$ is that the error terms might not "cancel out" nicely. 

For example, consider those primes $p>\sqrt{x}$. For each such prime, there are exactly $[\frac{x}{p}]$ integers $\leq x$ divisible by $p$. Thus we end up with $$\sum_{\sqrt{x}<p\leq x} \chi(p)\left[\frac{x}{p}\right]=x\sum \frac{\chi(p)}{p}+\sum \chi(p)\left\{\frac{x}{p} \right\}$$

It seems very hard to handle the term $$\sum_{\sqrt{x}<p\leq x} \chi(p)\left\{\frac{x}{p} \right\}.$$

Comment: @NilotpalSinha: I wanted to ask if you could try fitting the specific model $f_3(n)-f_1(n) \approx Cn^{0.75}$ and see how this does?

Comment: @EricNaslund The data seems to suggest that the true exponent is somewhere close to $0.75$. For $n = 104253000000$, $\frac{\ln(f_3(n) - f_1(n))}{\ln n} \approx 0.744893792393631$ and this ratio of the logarithms have an increasing trend so it is possible that it approaches $3/4$. Later, I will fit a proper function of the form $Cn^{3/4}$ see how the constant $C$ is behaving. Do you have any heuristics to suggest that the exponent must be $3/4$?

Comment: @NilotpalSinha: Unfortunately there was a mistake in the approach I used, I'm not sure how to handle the small primes, so I am not sure if $n^{0.75}$ is correct.

Comment: @EricNaslund May be you can share the intuition/heuristics that initially led you to believe that the true exponent might be $0.75$ and high the difficulty in this approach